# loading view with with different query result coming from model(search module) codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

developing a search module with different parameter supplied with form.

And Controller is like that

```
public function searchCourse()
{  
     $cat_id = $this->input->post('searchkey');
     $course_id = $this->input->post('searchkey_course');
     //$start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('fromDate')));
     $course_name = $this->input->post('searchbyname');
     $university_id = $this->session->userdata('university_id');
     $data['course'] = $this->crud_model->getcourseSearch($university_id, $course_id, $course_name);
     $data['page_title'] = 'My Course';
     $this->load->view('frontend/university/mycourse', $data);

}
```

Model:

```
 public function getcourseSearch($param1 = '', $param2 = false, $param4= false)

 {    

   $this->db->select('*');

   $this->db->where('coursep_id', $param1);

   if($param2){
       $this->db->like('name_of_course', $param2);

   }

   if($param4){
       $this->db->or_like('name_of_course', $param4, 'both');
   }

   $query=$this->db->get("course");

   return $query->result();

   }
```

The problem:
           The problem is first time view is loading with list of data. which is fine but when form being submitted with search params views are being stacked with different result data. how can i overcome this.

Comment: different in what way? what is the difference? If you identify the search pattern difference, it's easier to identify the source of the problem

Comment: when i first load the view there is university id from session data which is param1 in model function.

Comment: secondly when someone select search from other parameter is taken into consideration. that time view get stacked one after another

Comment: and that other parameter would be...

Comment: What do you mean by the views are being stacked? Is the view rendering multiple times?

Comment: yes.. with header footer also

Comment: @ShuvadeepChakraborty didn't understood. can you elobarate more about this please

Comment: i find out why view are getting stacked. Now please review my model function as i wanted to search with multiple parameter like course name, starting date from a single table. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling this function in model, you are passing three parameters $university_id, $course_id, $course_name.

so $param1= university_id, $param2=course_id and $param4=course_name.

use proper parameter while formatting query.

Like:
public function getcourseSearch($param1 = '', $param2 = false, $param4= false)

{

$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->where('coursep_id', $param2);

if($param2){
       $this->db->like('name_of_course', $param4);

}

$query=$this->db->get("course");

return $query->result();

}

Comment: should i free result when second time page is load. data variable holds the first query data.

Comment: No need, when page gets load second time data variable will have fresh data.

Comment: if you are working with pagination then refer following link:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html